# Is “cheese-stick operation, manufacturing, building current word?

Tags: word-usage, contemporary-english

I was drawn to the word, “cheese-stick” appearing in the article titled, “[The book that didn’t exist](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/04/14/the-book-that-didnt-exist/?hp&rref=opinion)” in the Opinion Pages of the New York Times (April 14), which deals with the art and craft of writing. It reads:

> We had collaborated on a project that began a decade earlier. Ruth, a children’s book editor at Random House, was a regular reader of my stories and perhaps the only reader of a manuscript I wrote in my Alphabet City apartment, among my first in New York. It was a sixth-floor walk-up with a **cheese-stick operation** on the ground floor. A byproduct of **cheese-stick manufacturing** is a vomit-like smell.

None of CED, OED and Merriam-Webster carries “cheese-stick” although they carry “cheesecake” and “cheese steak.” I can’t find the word on Google Ngram too.

From the context, I surmise “cheese-stick” means “makeshift, sloppy or fragile” operations and construction, but I’m not sure.

What does it mean? Is the word in current use with that meaning?

Comment: I would think a *"cheese stick"* is just a stick made of cheese. Making cheese (whether it is shaped into sticks or not) is a notoriously smelly operation.

Comment: As the answer notes; [literal cheese sticks](https://www.google.com/search?q=cheese+stick&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ouhNU-SqH5eeyAT3mYCwBw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1286&bih=708) are very much a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it literally means a stick of cheese, such as string cheese.  However, in New York Mozzarella sticks would make sense; many small companies specialize in making a particular type of food in a small building.  This reminds me of a recent article in the New Yorker about fresh mozzarella making in NYC a few decades ago.  Since Mozzarella sticks are what comes up when you Google cheese stick, I think that's what it is.

I really don't think cheese-stick is being used metaphorically here; I've never heard of that expression and it doesn't really make sense.